# WordPress Checking if post exists with category outside loop

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm adding a alert section to my blog, that only shows the content of posts that are included within the "alert" category and are "sticky".

This all works as it should. I'm wondering now how I can hide the wrapping div that shows these alerts if none exist.

This is what I have so far...

```
        /* This is the if statement that i'm having trouble with */
                <?php if (have_posts() && in_category('alert')) {?>
        /* Below here works fine */

<div id="alert">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
            <div class="ticker">
                <ul>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            if(is_sticky() && in_category('alert')) {?>
                <li>
                <strong><?php the_title(); ?> - </strong>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                </li>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Your query is completely wrong, ineffecient and your code breaks the main query. Never ever use `query_posts`

Comment: Instead of `query_posts`, check out function [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object, so you may be extract the set of posts you want.

Comment: I've updated my code to use `is_sticky()` instead of `query_posts`

Comment: @PieterGoosen, It wasn't sarcasm... I took it on-board and updated my code :)

Comment: Ok, sorry for that misunderstanding, have posted a solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already stated in comments, you should never ever use `query_posts` as it breaks the main query object, and many plugins and custom code relies on this object. If you **have to** run a custom query, use `WP_Query`or `get_posts`.

Secondly, your query is ineffecient and wasteful. You are currently querying all sticky posts and then skipping posts **inside** the loop with the use of conditional tags. All of this runs unnecessary db calls which wastes resources.

To correct your issue, we will:

- `WP_Query` and set `no_found_rows` to true to skip paging as we don't need pagination
- use `ignore_sticky_posts` to ignore sticky posts to be moved to the front
- use the `cat` (use category ID) or `category_name` (uses category **slug**) parameter to get posts from the specific category

You can try something like this: (*I'm not going to code the loop, but you need use yours, just remember to remove the conditional checks, `is_sticky()` and `in_category()`*)

```
$stickies = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
if ( $stickies ) {
    $args = [
        'post__in' => $stickies,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'no_found_rows' => true,
        'cat' => 1, // Change to correct ID
        //'category_name' => 'cat-slug',
    ];
    $q = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();

            // YOUR LOOP

        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

### EDIT

I have slipped up here. When there are no sticky posts, `get_option( 'sticky_posts' )` will return an empty array. If you pass an empty array to `post__in`, it will return **all** posts. It is a stupid bug in the `WP_Query` class. IMHO, an empty array should result in no posts. I have updated the code to gaurd againt this

Comment: Just one thing on my code, I use the new short array syntax (`[]`) which needs PHP5.4+. If you have an older version, change this back to the old array syntax (`array()`)

Comment: Thanks, weirdly it's not respecting the `sticky_posts` and displays anything that's posted under the `category_name` alert

Comment: Ag crap, I suspect what the issue is, it slipped me to incorporate the following, sorry about that, if you pass an empty array to `post__in`, it does return **all** posts. This is a stupid bug in the `WP_Query` class. IMHO, the expected outcome should be zero posts. But anyway, this is how the cookie crumbles, :-). I will update my answer

Comment: Superstar, thanks. `WP_Query` seems quite powerful and simple to use... Brushing up on using this now.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. It is really worth into looking into `WP_Query`, even the main query uses it. Another tip, use `pre_get_posts` if you ever need to adjust the main query on the home and any archive pages :-). Just for interest sake, check out [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545)